# Different text on different sites in a multisite setup

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, multisite

I have a multisite setup with say two websites and both of them use the same theme.

Now, I want to use the same theme for both of the websites but want to change texts in few places. say the "read more" button in website1 should show "show more" for website2.

What solution I have thought of:

Duplicating the theme. And then change the texts in the duplicated version and activate that for my second theme.

I guess that will work. But I thought to ask this question to know if there is a better way to do it with a plugin or some code to detect which site I am on.

Since using a duplicate theme, I might have to repeat myself when I do some design changes.

Comment: I don't believe there is a beautiful solution to your issue. You could use [get_current_blog_id](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_current_blog_id) to find the active website. I would suggest you put in the hard coded ID's in your wp-config.php file. Something like:

    `define('WEBSITEX_ID', 1);`
    `define('WEBSITEY_ID', 2);`

Another option would be the usage of a multi-language plugin like [WPML](http://www.wpml.org) or a language file. Then you can either use two different languages or point to a different language file based on the website ID.

Comment: thanks @Frank . Got the idea of using `get_current_blog_id`. but got two doubts - 1. can I point one site on my multisite setup to use a language file without using any multi-language plugin. 2. I could not understand your point of `define('WEBSITEX_ID', 1); ` and `define('WEBSITEY_ID',  ` . How can I define two ID's for two different sites on wp-config.php?

Comment: both website use same  language ? if both site use different language you can translate this text

Comment: @HasiburRahaman Both the sites are on same language. they both use the same theme. I just want different texts for a few elements.

Comment: instant of creation duplicate theme you can create some extra template for those page which you want to change.

Comment: @HasiburRahaman. Thanks, for the idea. I can create a child theme and use only the necessary templates. I hadn't thought of that. how silly to copy the entire theme.

Comment: With WEBSITEX_ID I mean that you hardcode the value of the blog ID. So in your template you can write something like `if(get_blog_id() == WEBITEX_ID)`, it makes it a bit more readable and if the ID ever changes (or is different in other environments) then you can simply configure it. As long as it is just a couple of templates that are affected then a child theme is a great suggestion as well yes.